# Optimising API calls to the same endpoint with different payloads

Tags: python, angular, api, rxjs, ngrx

I am currently facing an API problem in a large Angular Project. I am using rxjs 6 and there is an API that calculates the cost of the product for multiple dates & cities.

This API is called from multiple components and at a particular route, it is called from 3-4 components as the user changes their selection of dates.

This API is inside a service & it performs cost calculation. On Response, the frontend logic breaks down the rate into required components (Taxes, additional services cost etc.) and updates other subscribed values in the components.

The problem I am facing is as the user selects the dates quickly, multiple calls are fired with different payloads, but I want to cancel older API calls when the user starts a new selection.

Is there any way to do this? I tried storing the callback but it cancels random calls that leads to incorrect updates.

I cannot post the code, since its a huge chunk.

For a better understanding:

Consider Components A & B, Service C.
A shows the cities and the cost for each city.
B is a calendar that lets the user select the dates.
C calculates the cost and updates some variables, which are subscribed to in components A & B.

When the user selects a date in component B, the cost API is called for all the cities in component A. So if the user selects multiple dates in a quick manner, a lot of APIs are called. This causes a difference in the cost especially if the network is unstable. Older API responses sometimes replace and show the wrong cost.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: @RafiHenig Hi, code is rather large and spread across multiple files. I have added some more description as an edit. Hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: Is there a usecase for selecting multiple dates?

Comment: This is a use case for `switchMap`. `switchMap` automatically unsubscribes from an observable you mapped to when the source emits a new value. `userInput$.pipe(switchMap(value => apiCall(value)))`.

Comment: I agree with @fridoo, `switchMap` is your friend. You can also use `debounceTime` to prevent requests being sent instantly when the user changes something, as well as `distinctUntilChanged` to not send redundant sequential requests.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a minimal reproduction of your issue.  Also adding a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) would make it even easier :-). But generally speaking, [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) will be helpful for you in this scenario, but probably only one piece of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `switchMap` to cancel previous HTTP calls, and you want to use `debounceTime` to fire the API call only once when the underlying values change quickly.

E.g.

```
combineLatest([trigger1$, trigger2$]).pipe(
   debounceTime(250),
   switchMap(values => this.http.post(url, values))
).subscribe(response => console.log(response)
```

Where trigger1$, trigger2$ can be Subjects/BehaviorSubjects into which you `.next()` the values.

For example, you can have

```
const date$ = new Subject<Date>();
const query$ = new Subject<string>();
```

and these would be your triggers for the HTTP call.